# How to make two commutative fields unique in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection like this:

```js
{ 'start_location': '1', 'end_location': '2' },
{ 'start_location': '3', 'end_location': '4' }
```

I want to make sure that following entries  cannot be inserted:

```js
{ 'start_location': '1', 'end_location': '2' }
```

or

```js
{ 'start_location': '2', 'end_location': '1' }
```

Although such an entry should be allowed:

```js
{ 'start_location': '1', 'end_location': '3' }
```

I tried doing compound index but could not succeed.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes cannot enforce logic like this for you, but you can build in the logic so that creation is only possible where the paired combination exists. In order to do this you need to use the ["upsert"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) functionality and only put your modifications inside a [**`$setOnInsert`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) block

```js
db.startend.update(
   {
       "$or": [
            { "start_location": "2", "end_location": "1" },
            { "start_location": "1", "end_location": "2" }
       ]
   },
   {

       "$setOnInsert": {
           "start_location": "2",
           "end_location": "1"
       }
   },
   { "upsert": true }
)
```

Will match a document with `"start_location": "1"` and `"end_location": "2"`, and therefore not create a new document. However if the combination does not exist:

```js
db.startend.update(
   {
       "$or": [
            { "start_location": "1", "end_location": "3" },
            { "start_location": "3", "end_location": "1" }
       ]
   },
   {

       "$setOnInsert": {
           "start_location": "1",
           "end_location": "3"
       }
   },
   { "upsert": true }
)
```

Then a new document is created.

So the [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) condition allows you to specifiy the combination in the reverse order of arguments as well as your intended order, so you can compare for each possible match.

Under an "upsert" the new document gets created when the conditions are not met or you can place any modification you might want to make outside of the `$setOnInsert` block, such as this [**`$inc`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) to increment a value on each match, where you deliberately want to do that:

```js
db.startend.update(
   {
       "$or": [
            { "start_location": "2", "end_location": "1" },
            { "start_location": "1", "end_location": "2" }
       ]
   },
   {

       "$setOnInsert": {
           "start_location": "2",
           "end_location": "1"
       },
       "$inc": { "counter": 1 }
   },
   { "upsert": true }
)
```

So as stated, indexes are not the way to enforce this logic, but specifying your "forward" and "reverse" conditions within the statement is a relatively easy pattern to follow and implement for "insertion/updates".

---

As a word of caution, doing a little more research on this might lead you to consider an array format using the "start" and "end" as two array positions like this:

```js
{ "location": [ "1", "2" ] },
{ "location": [ "3", "4" ] }
```

And you might think this a good idea, as there is an [**`$all`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator which could be used here to essentially match in "any order" where "all" elements are present. However there is a "hidden catch" here in that this will actually fail with an error:

```js
db.startend.update(
   {
       "location": { "$all": [ "1", "3" ] }
   },
   {
        "$setOnInsert": {
            "location": [ "1", "3" ]
        }
   },
   { "upsert": true }
)
```

And the error will be:

> WriteResult({
>           "nMatched" : 0,
>           "nUpserted" : 0,
>           "nModified" : 0,
>           "writeError" : {
>                   "code" : 54,
>                   "errmsg" : "cannot infer query fields to set, path 'location' is matched twice"
>           }
>   })

Where you would reasonably expect that an "upsert" would occur here, but instead the error is produced. The specific problem here is because the data being compared is in an array, the update is "trying" to work out which "position" of the array to update, even though this is not what you are asking here.

In order to work around this, you need to force the query engine to "not" try to match the array position at all, and the only way to do that is with JavaScript evaluation of [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), to replace the logic of what `$all` is doing on the array comparision:

```js
db.startend.update(
   {
       "$where": function() {
           var input = [ "1", "3" ];

           return this.location.every(function(el) {
               return ( input.indexOf(el) != -1 );
           });
       }
   },
   {
        "$setOnInsert": {
            "location": [ "1", "3" ]
        }
   },
   { "upsert": true }
)
```

And while that logic will hold correctly, it is not really desirable and the `$where` condition here cannot use an index for lookups and this means the expression must always scan every document in the collection in order to to determine where there is or isn't a match.

So the caveat there is that something that might have looked good on the surface and was going to take some complexity out of your coded process, actually ends up being a huge performance problem.